# Woocommerce - Shop can't find products after domain name change

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce on my Wordpress site. Today I changed its domain name and since then, my shop doesn't see any of my products.
I created a new test product after the migration and that one is displayed.

I have tried going in the product permalinks settings and clicking save changes, like it is often suggested, but it didn't fix the problem. All the product urls and permalinks seem to have the new domain name applied to them.

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a Search and Replace plugin to replace the old domain name with the new one?

I like the "Better Search and Replace". It has a 'test' mode that will tell you what will change without changing it. That would tell you if there are any links to the old domain name in the database.

Comment: I tried opening each product and simply saving it. This did the trick but the products appeared "Out of stock", even though inventory is not managed for them. I caved in and recreated them

Comment: I have no knowledge of how WooCommerce stores things in their database, but I'd bet that there are table rows that have the URL in them. So a Search and Replace plugin would tell you (the one I mentioned has a 'test' mode, so you can see where the changes would be done). But this question is better asked on the WooCommerce support forum, rather than here.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll give it a shot. Have a great day

Comment: Hope my answer helped. It's always useful to others here if you describe your solution, and/or checkmark an answer as the solution. Sharing solutions that worked is a big part of this place.